# mathematically incorrect fit coefficients in python curve_fit

Tags: python-3.x

The definition of a power law is A*(x-D)^B+C. Mathematically. In this case, I want the power law to have a singularity at zero.

```
def powerlaw(x,a,b,c):
    return a*x**b+c

xdat=np.arange(len(USAarr))
ydat0=np.sort(USAarr[:,0])
ydat=ydat0[::-1]
par=[1.,1.,1.,1.]
p0=par
par,pvar=curve_fit(powerlaw,xdat,ydat)


p=figure(height=400,width=400,title="Power law fit to v/c histogram",\
    x_axis_label="v/c", y_axis_label="ratio of counts")
p.vbar(x=index, width=0.5, bottom=0, top=ydat, color='cyan',\ 
    legend='v/c data')
p.line(index, powerlaw(index,par[0],par[1],par[2]),color='black',\
    legend='power law fit')
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

[image]

`par=array([-0.1001773 ,  0.16004007,  0.44202822])`

This power law fit is one of two excellent fits to my data (based on the graphical depiction by bokeh) but the output parameters are wrong. For a decreasing exponent with a positive offset in the positive quadrant, a>0, b<0, c>0 by definition. Yet that is not what I obtain here.

Do any python experts know what could be going wrong with `curve_fit` or `bokeh`?

Comment: For positive exponents the exponential function is increasing. But for every increasing function f(x), function a*f(x) where a < 0 is decreasing, so the coefficients make total sense to me. Not sure why do you think something is wrong here.

Comment: Like @BartoszKP says, with a positive value for `c`, `a` does not have to be >0 for the result to be positive, and `a` is not > 0 by definition -- in fact it looks like it should be negative.  Indeed, you can verify that -0.1 * 500 ** 0.16 + 0.44 ~= 0.17 and that -0.1 * 2000 ** 0.16 + 0.44 ~= 0.1, so the result does not look too far off.